# Searchkick filter with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, searchkick

Has anybody used Searchkick with a scoped model?

I have an `Article` model with `scope :published, ->{ where(status: "Published") }`.
So In my `ArticleController`  I did the following:

`query = params[:q].presence || "*"
@search = Article.published.search(query, operator: "or", suggest: true)`

but it didn't work https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/140 and kept including all the records

So I did:

`query = params[:q].presence || "*"
@search = Article.search(query, where:{status: "Published"}, operator: "or", suggest: true)`

Didn't work either... and returned nothing.
Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: That issue #140 seems to be unsolved yet.

Wondering why this second one with `where` didn't work, are you sure it is `Published` and not `published`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to add `status` to the `search_data` hash

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  searchkick highlight: [:title], text_start: [:title], language: "spanish"

  scope :draft,     ->{ where(status: "Draft") }
  scope :published, ->{ where(status: "Published") }
  scope :scheduled, ->{ where(status: "Scheduled") }

  def search_data
    {
      title: title,
      content: content,
      status: status     <--------
    }
  end
```